# How to change whole layout page in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

In my layout project I want to change layout color.

**layout/default.vue**

```html
<v-app>
   ....
</v-ap>
```

I need to change v-app color, but this doesn't work:

```html
<v-app color="secondary">
```

How can I do it?

**note**: I just want to use a Vuetify variable, like `primary`, `secondary`, `accent`, etc., and not CSS code.

Comment: There is nothing like this in [the API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-app/). [v-theme-provider](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-theme-provider/) is available only for light/dark. So, I'm not sure where you saw this one but is it even possible?

Comment: Also, what do you expect here exactly? Passing `red-500` and that you whole page turns red?

Comment: i want to use light and dark them and beacuse of that i need to use these variables like : primary , secondary and ...

Comment: i want to set whole document background color and becacuse of that i set color for v-app

Comment: <template><v-app class="something" /><template>

<style>
.something{
   background-color:$primary ;
</style>

is it possible to do it like this ????

Answer (score 0):

i found it
in **layout page** i added this

```
#app {
    background-color: var(--v-background-base) !important;
}
```

and in the nuxt config , in vuetify config
themes: {
light: {
background :'#eee'
},
dark :{
background :'#fff'
}
}